# Сервер с защитой от DDOS

Tags: ddos, vps, сервер

Все привет!

Недавно боролся c `SQL injection` теперь дело дошло и до `DDOS`. Подскажите где можно арендовать `VPS` или Выделенный сервер с защитой от `DDOS`. А то захожу на многие сайты, все же про себя как обычно пишут, что мол у нас 100% защита и т.д. А аренда сервера с защитой от `DDOS` дело не дешевое, так что хотелось бы не обжечься.

В общем жду Ваших ответов, и заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую https://ddos-guard.net/#/en/dedicated - тут есть и сервера и VPS, тарифы на VPS уточняйте у саппорта. Ребята знают свое дело. очень качественная защита от ddos атак.

Comment: человек даже зарегистрировался чтобы подсказать вам :D

Comment: За ответ безусловно огромное спасибо, но мне пока не по карману..... Но на будущее буду иметь ввиду!

Answer (score 0):

Если нужны более лояльные тарифы, спросите у Симпливей о ДДоС защите - http://simplyway.net/ru/ddos-protection.html

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте CloudFlare. При несильных DDoS-атаках (<10000 клиентов) ваш сайт будет грузиться, но при более сильных сайт могут временно отключить от 2 часов до 1 дня максимум

Answer (score 0):

Я арендую сервера в компании http://sartelekom.ru  Пользуюсь пол года работает отлично. На сайте много выгодных предложений по аренде серверов. Скорость передачи 100 Мб

Answer (score 0):

эм, ну могу предложить [ukraine com ua](http://www.ukraine.com.ua/)

я доволен

Answer (score -1):

Могу посоветовать http://protectwire.ru/, отличная защита от ddos, пользуюсь недавно

Comment: Интересно, а сколько за это время было атак и как Вы оценивали разницу в обслуживании во время атаки и без нее?

--

Кстати, ссылка не работает

(рекомендую удалить лишнюю запятую в ее тексте).

Comment: ссылка вообще не работает. даже после того как убрать запятую :)